# How to create dynamic substore or substate with ngxs

Tags: ngxs

I have created a module to manage my CRUD scaffolding. I currently define a context which I define for all my "collections" based on the URL in the router. ie: #/posts/admin tells me the collection is posts and my scaffolding is a list #/posts/admin/edit/xxxx is scaffolding for editing post xxxx. For each type of scaffolding I defined list of fields and actions. It is working fine but I would like to replace with with States from NGXS.

My thinking would be to define a base State for each scaffolding screens and then for each collection to create a substate.

How do you create a State which can be extended with its own set of actions.

Comment: I am also having the same issue, did you figure it out?

Comment: not really. I have added a map outside of my state which I access depending of an argument I pass in my actions which is an id for my component (or in my case collection). Then my selector are actually createSelector and take that id as a first argument. Not happy with that setup but it works. Just waiting for something better come along which I will refactor surely when it is ready

Comment: there is actually a plugin I need to study ngxs/form-plugin which I think has to deal with something similar.

Comment: I was able to get it to work https://github.com/ngxs/store/issues/593

Comment: looks like you use exactly the same setup I did. However I dont see you using any Selectors or StateModel. 

Your GetCollection is worrisome as you are subscribing in it with no unsubscribing anywhere.  Maybe what you are trying to do should be done with a static createSelector method.

static getCollection(coll:string) {
    return createSelector (state: StateModel) { return .... }
}
A few things I am concerned is the lost of state history in my own implementation. My understanding of state management is that between each iteration the state in kept in memory to be undo.

Comment: The service I am using unsubscribes automatically after the response